# Custom cells - how can I separate out tweets into componentsseparatedbyString

Tags: xcode, tableview

I have a custom cell in a tableview. All connections are made. I am conducting a Twitter search. The results of this propagate a custom cell in a tableView. I would like to separate the individual tweets out into an array using componentsseparatedbystring so that I can assign these to 4 labels in my custom cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
    - (void)fetchTweets
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json"]];

            NSError* error;

            tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        });
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return tweets.count;

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

        customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
                // added this bit in
            cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


        }

       // THIS IS THE BIT I'M STRUGGLING WITH
// I'M GUESSING THAT THIS LINE SEPARATES THE TWEETS INTO SINGLE TWEETS?
        NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// I THEN CREATE AN ARRAY TO HOLD MY COMPONENTS OF THE TWEET SO THAT I CAN SPLIT FOR MY LABELS
        NSArray *arrayForCustomCell = [[NSArray alloc] init];

        arrayForCustomCell = [tweet componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];





        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: how tweet dictionary output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already parsed the results in your async call. Now, you have an array of 'tweet' dictionaries and you can grab any value like this:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *tweetText = [tweet valueForKey:@"text"];
NSString *tweetCountry = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"place.country"] //Nested property
```

and then you just set your `UILabels`. You get the idea...

Comment: Ok - thanks. I need to split the individual tweets into sections that will be separated by a ":" so could I do... NSDictionary *tweet = [[tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; or do I need to create an array first? Thanks again

Comment: No, you cannot call `componentsSeparatedByString` on a dictionary. What I was trying to tell you is that you already have each tweet as `NSDictionary` in your `tweets` array.

Comment: Thanks, therefore how would I then create an array from the tweet separating the tweet into 4 components separated by the ":"? Thanks

Comment: Each of your tweets is already 'separated' into multiple key/value pairs because is a dictionary, there is no need to do so. I really cannot understand why you feel the need to separate by ":". Imagine that your parser already separated all your objects on ":" when you deserialized the JSON on your `fetchTweets` method.

Comment: That is because the tweet would have.... "componentA:componentB:componentC:componentD" and I need to grab them out of the tweet and assign to different lables - I will only actually need the tweet detail (the 140 characters), not the user if that makes sense?

Comment: Please see (and try) my answer. This is **exactly** what I am doing. I am grabbing the 'text' _component_ (the 140 chars) and another one as an example.

Comment: Ok, I suppose I could make an array from that string - thanks for your help